# Recommendations for inter-app audio apps for GarageBand?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, garageband

I have so far learnt to use Apple loops and thirsty to learn more: more loops, try some inter-app audio apps and so on. Please recommend inter audio apps for GarageBand.

Answer (score 1):

From [WTF Is Inter-App Audio Apps?](http://thegaragebandguide.com/wtf-is-inter-app-audio-apps)

Here’s a list of the apps that currently work with Inter-App Audio in Garageband:

[Alchemy mobile](http://www.camelaudio.com/AlchemyMobile.php)
[Amplitube](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/cat-view.php?C=family-amplitube) (iPhone and iPad, paid and free versions)
[Magellan](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/magellan/id544119998?mt=8)
[Nave](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id596036905)
[Yamaha TNR-i](http://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/apps/tnr-i/)
[Yamaha Mobile Sequencer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobile-music-sequencer-us/id580022906)
[Yamaha Synth Arp & Drum Pad](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/apps/synth_arp/)
[AUFX:Space](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aufx-space/id665650685)
[NLogSynth Pro](http://www.temporubato.com/index.php?page=ProdPRO)
[iMini](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/imini/id603340125?mt=8)
[Galileo Organ](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/galileo-organ/id644077827)

Answer (score 0):

Today you can use [this website](http://synthyfrog.com/) to get full list of Inter-App Audio supported apps:

- [All Inter-App Audio compatible apps](http://synthyfrog.com/technology-is-interapp/)
- [Inter-App Audio compatible Instruments](http://synthyfrog.com/technology-is-interapp/type-is-instrument/)
- [Inter-App Audio compatible Effects](http://synthyfrog.com/technology-is-interapp/type-is-effect/)

Also, you can filter apps by sounds, effect types and more.